# why am I getting the numerical value of 0 instead of 1?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm sure some of you are tired of my posts since they seem to be pretty basic but I've run into a similar problem with "mysql_result()". My code keeps outputting this error:

```
Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\Image Upload\func\user.func.php on line 10
```

when I've checked for backticks being in the right spot..I don't see where my error could be..here's the code:

```
function login_check($email, $password){
       $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
       $login_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT (`user_id`) as `count`, `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `password` = '".md5($password)."'");
       return (mysql_result($login_query, 0) == 1) ? mysql_result($login_query, 0, '$user_id') : false;
}
```

Here is line 10:

```
return (mysql_result($login_query, 0) == 1) ? mysql_result($login_query, 0, '$user_id') : false;
```

Thanks for all the patience and help! 
-TechGuy24

Comment: `echo mysql_error();` PS: you don't need `COUNT(...)` there. Just check if there is a `user_id` in a response

Comment: **1.** Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). **2.** Use prepared statements, `*_escape_string` can be worked around. **3.** Use Try-Catch-Throw. (example: `if(!$conn) throw new Exception('Could not connect to the database server!');`)

Answer (score 2):

Syntax error:

```
$login_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT (`user_id`) as `count`, `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `password` = '".md5($password)."'");
                                                        ^--   ^--
```

backticks are used to escape reserved words in field/table specifications. an `as` alias does not need to be escaped, as it's obviously not a field/table name.

You are also using an aggregate function, `count()`, but also selecting non-aggregate fields (`user_id`), without a `group by` clause, so mysql will complain about that too.

If your code was structure as follows:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

you'd see the syntax error messages. Never assume a query has suceeded. ALWAYS check for errors. Even if your SQL syntax is 100% perfect, there's far too many other reasons for failure to not check.

Answer (score 0):

As zerkms said, you don't need `COUNT`.

The problem: `COUNT` doesn't like spaces between it and the parentheses, so:

```
COUNT (
```

should be

```
COUNT(
```

---

**EDIT:**

This should work better:

**SQL:**

```
SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '<email>' AND `password` = '<hash>'
```

**PHP:**

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
$login = mysql_result($result);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) return false;
return $login['user_id'];
```

By the way, you are at risk of...

```
SQL INJECTION    *------==========[');SQL--|----]=====0
```

You should use MySQLi or PDO, with prepared statements.

Comment: I took out the space in between count that was there..now I'm getting this error: "Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: $user_id not found in MySQL result index 11 in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\Image Upload\func\user.func.php on line 10" ... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @TechGuy24 Try taking out the backticks around `user_id`, and see if that works.

Comment: @TechGuy24 What about `SELECT COUNT(\`user_id\`), \`user_id\` AS \`count\`, \`user_id\` FROM ...`?

Comment: didn't do anything. I still have that error.

Comment: no difference, I still get the same error.

Comment: Never mind..I fixed it..turns out I shouldn't have made the "user_id" on line 10 a variable...dumb error :P Thanks for all the patience and help! It was greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there was an error in executing the SQL statement `mysql_query` only returns a resource on success. On error, it returns `false` (see [PHP Manual on mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)). That explains the error, since you are calling `mysql_result` with the values `false` as the first parameter.

Comment: Sorry about the duplicate answer on this post. Deleting it now.